# Why functions with arguments can be called without arguments in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a question regarding pyomo. I have seen quite often, that for the definition of parameters, objectives and constraints, explicit functions are defined. These functions expect some arguments and in Pyomo most often they are not passed when calling. I do not understand how this is possible. Here is an example (taken from https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/doc-testbuild/pyomo_modeling_components/Parameters.html)

```
def s_init(model, i, j):
    if i == j:
        return i*i
    else:
        return 0.0
model.S2 = pyo.Param(model.A, model.A, initialize=s_init)
```

The function `s_init` requires 3 parameters: `model`, `i`, `j`. However when calling the function no parameter is being passed `initialize=s_init`. So I am wondering how this is possible? While the parameter model has been defined (maybe it can be regarded as a static variable like in Java), I have no clue where the function takes the parameters `i` and `j` from.

Can anybody tell me more about this? I'd appreciate every comment and will be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: Pyomo takes model.A to define i and j. If model.A = [1,2,3], Pyomo will iterate over this set to define i and j.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steven. But why can I call a function without any arguments altough the function s_init requires 3 arguments?

Comment: You are passing the function instead of calling it (note the absence of parenthesis) and then pyomo internally calls it. https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/7185942a18b66ae15accbd8cd6bba607039fc5dd/pyomo/core/base/misc.py#L53

Comment: But where do the values i an j come from that I never specified?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stradivari. But still I do not get where i and j come from. They are not defined at all in the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the syntax used in your specific example, `s_init` is most likely used as a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

Here's a simple Python example of how this works:

```
>>> def get_square(val):
...     """The callback."""
...     return val ** 2
...
>>> def caller(func, val):
...     return func(val)
...
>>> caller(get_square, 5)
25
```

More broadly speaking, many languages, including Python and C++, also provide syntax for optional arguments to methods. Depending on the language/syntax used, they don't even need to be in a specific order. If you don't provide everything, default values will be used instead for that method, assuming the developer has coded that logic into that specific method. `Param()` has optional arguments, so you need to tell Python that the third argument (`s_init`) should be used to populate a variable called `initialize` with data.

In this particular case, this data is a reference to the function (`s_init`). You can tell by the lack of parentheses. `s_init()` would call the function, while `s_init` is a reference to the function. What happens next really depends on how that information is used by Param, but syntactically this is simply passing a reference as an optional argument.

Comment: Thanks Nikos for your answer. So what is basically done in the line "model.S2 = pyo.Param(model.A, model.A, initialize=s_init)". Is pyo.Param() a function that expects 3 arguments? One of these arguments is "initialize". When calling the pyo.Param() function we assign the function s-init to it. But why and how is the s_init function now executed? Someone has to execute it and I do not see it in the code. Is this done within the pyo.Param() function?

Comment: Further,  I do not understand what you are talking about in the first paragraph of your answer about the functions with optional arguments. But I guess this is not so important.

Comment: `initialize` is the name of the input argument that the Pyomo devs defined for this, e.g., `def Param(nikos=x,initialize=some_function)`. When you invoke Param you can specify which input argument `s_init` corresponds to by using its name: `initialize=s_init`. This syntax is used because Param() has numerous optional arguments, so you need to specify that the third argument you are passing is used to populate the `initialize` variable with data (in this case a reference to `s_init`)

Comment: @PeterBe I also updated the answer, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Thanks Nikos for your further answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I still do not understand in my example, where the arguments i an j in the defintion of the funciton "def s_init(model, i, j) " come from. The are never passed to this function and this requires them. Further they - as opposed to the model variable - they are never defined in the code. I assume that the model variable itself is a static variable meaning that it is available also in other classes (otherwise I would also not understand where the Param function takes this from). But for the i and j I am quite confused

Comment: Further, I am questioning what sense it makes to use such a concept of passing whole functions instead of just calling them. In your posted example, why do you use this intermediate function "caller" if you want to just calculate the "get_square" value of an argument? For me it just increases the complexity without having any benefit.

Comment: The Pyomo guys designed a language within Python, so when it comes to designing a language with certain user-level syntax and flexibility in mind, design choices need to be made for technical reasons that do not make sense from the outside. In this case, this syntax allows you, the user, to create your own bespoke piece of logic in a function, and then inject that logic into Param(). Note that this way you do not need to pass any numbers associated with the results of the calculations of s_init within Param. It also allows you to define s_init once and reuse that logic.

Comment: Thanks Nikos for your further answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I still do not understand in my example, where the arguments i an j in the defintion of the funciton "def s_init(model, i, j) " come from. The are never passed to this function and this requires them. Further they - as opposed to the model variable - they are never defined in the code. I assume that the model variable itself is a static variable meaning that it is available also in other classes (otherwise I would also not understand where the Param function takes this from). But for the i and j I am quite confused

Comment: Hi Nikos. Thanks for your answer. Can you say something about my last comment? I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: @PeterBe This is quite a lengthy topic that unfortunately goes beyond the scope of comments. Since this is really a programming question (rather than an OR one) I encourage you to post a question on StackOverflow about the Python-specific details of the syntax used here.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Your are saying that this is not a Pyomo specific topic but rather a Python one? Then I will ask this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer